# Tails signature mismatch

Tags: tails, verification

So I downloaded the new signing key with Key-ID 0x58ACD84F. However, the detatched signature file for Tails 1.3.2 seems to be signed with Key-ID 0x752A3DB6 and I can't seem to find that particular key mentioned anywhere on the website. It does show up on the keyservers, though. Is that the old one? Should I trust it?

Edit: I see now that 0x752A3DB6 is a subkey of 0x58ACD84F. Why would Kleopatra claim there's "Not enough information to check signature validity"?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had failed to trust/certify that signing key. Once I did that, I received a "green" result. This Reddit post highlights the solution quite thoroughly:

https://www.reddit.com/r/tails/comments/30d24r/problem_verifying_tails_131/